# NetLogo: the meaning of TO-REPORT explained for dummies?

Tags: report, netlogo, patch

I have a problem to understand the role of `to-report` and `report` in NetLogo, even it seems pretty useful and I can't really find a help written in "human style" language.

In NetLogo dictionnary http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#report  I can find definitions for `to-report` :

```
to-report procedure-name
to-report procedure-name [input1 ...]
Used to begin a reporter procedure.

The body of the procedure should use report to report a value for the procedure. See report.
```

and for `report`:

```
report value
Immediately exits from the current to-report procedure and reports value as the result of that procedure. report and to-report are always used in conjunction with each other. See to-report for a discussion of how to use them.
```

So, it seems `to-report` and `report`  calculate some value and report it.

Thus, when I try add

```
to-report average [a b c]
  report (a + b + c) / 2
end
```

to my code, and then use the `average` variable somewhere in my code p.e.:

```
to go 
  ...
  print average 
  tick
end
```

I've got an error: `AVERAGE expected 3 inputs`. When I try to create my variables [a b c] in `globals [a b c]` I've got an error `There is already a global variable called A`. 
If I define my variables `[a b c]` within `to-report` procedure:

```
to-report average [a b c]
    set a 1
  set b 2
  set c 3
  report (a + b + c) / 2
end
```

My error is again `AVERAGE expected 3 inputs`.

Thus, **how can I simply test the usefulness of to-report procedure? And where to place it correctly in my code to see what it is really doing?** From Urban Suite - Economic Disparity  (http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/UrbanSuite-EconomicDisparity) I see that to-report is used to calculate values related to each patch:

```
to-report patch-utility-for-poor
    report ( ( 1 / (sddist / 100 + 0.1) ) ^ ( 1 - poor-price-priority ) ) * ( ( 1 / price ) ^ ( 1 + poor-price-priority ) )
end
```

however this reported value is not directly defined as patch variable which increase my confusion...

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can take some input (usually one or more variables or values) and return some output (usually a single value). You can specify that a function returns a value using to-report in your function header and report returns the actual value.

Your error is due to the fact that you never passed in arguments to your average function

```
to go 
  ...
  print average 
  tick
end
```

should be

```
to go 
  ...
  print average 5 2 3 ;;a = 5, b = 2, c =3
  tick
end
```

Inside your average function, you should not reassign values of a,b,and c.

You should use report whenever you want to return a result from a function.